# Как зашифровать текст n-ой длинны шифром Фейстеля?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, шифрование

Я хочу зашифровать текст n-ой длинны шифром Фейстеля. Как правильно разбить текст на блоки? Я преобразовал строку к массиву байтов UTF8, и прикинул что блок - это 1 элемент массива. Но не понимаю как его разбить на две части. Хочу узнать как правильно разбить строку на блоки(узнать какого размера должны быть блоки) и как их делить на две части. В интернете прошерстил немало информации, но везде приводится в примерах либо работа с байтами либо с целочисленными значения, работу со строкой так и не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Нет никаких "байтов UTF8", есть просто байты. Строки, целые, UTF8 - интерпретация некой последовательности байт в памяти.
Далее, размер блока в блочном алгоритме - характеристика алгоритма. AES, например, работает с блоками в 128 бит (16 байт), соответственно размер зависит от алгоритма. Разбиение данных на блоки - последовательная выборка из данных соответствующего числа байт. Деление блока на 2 части - абсолютно аналогичная операция.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, понял в каком векторе двигаться дальше.

Comment: Чистая сеть фейстеля используется в DES, сорцы и стандарт на него общедоступны.

Comment: Первичны байты в памяти. Я одни и те же байты могут использовать как строку, как число и как исполняемый код. И именно поэтому строка - интерпретация.

Answer (score 0):

Понятия Шифр Фейстеля не существует. Но есть "Конструкция Сеть Фейстеля" и есть алгоритмы шифрования основанные на этой конструкции. Таким образом, если Вам нужно именно Фейстель, то вы ищите алгоритмы в описании которые есть "Feistel network". Только тогда можно говорить про реализацию.

Подробнее статья на habre: [Почему сеть Фейстеля работает? Объяснение «на пальцах»](http://habrahabr.ru/post/140404/) или википедиа: [Сеть Фейстеля](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%A4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F)